# iOS: Potential performance issue caused by Auto Layout

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

Recently, we found a performance issue with a tableView，which makes scrolling really bumpy or even hard to move. We've had this autolayout warning regarding to a UIImage's aspect ratio, saying

```
"Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x12d5dfa50 UIImageView:0x12f11f280.width == 2.33553*UIImageView:0x12f11f280.height>"
```

But since the UI works fine, so we did not pay attention to it until recently we found this performance issue occuring now and then. Unfortunately, we haven't find a way to reproduce the issue. I have heard that autolayout could need lots of computation, thus causing performance issues. I understand it might be caused by some other problems, but I wonder if this autolayout conflicts we have could be one of the culprits?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use Instruments to see where your app is spending time. There are many WWDC videos about it.

Comment: Eliminating the autolayout conflict is probably a good idea anyway